# Magento cache tag based on multiple products

Tags: cache

Is it possible to have a cache tag in Magento based on multiple products?

i.e. the cache storage is dependant on any 1 of a group of products being updated?

Comment: Doesn't the block cache do this natively? Or are you talking about some kind of FPC?

Comment: A custom cache, but not on a single product id, on multiple.  So i may have product id's 1,2,3,4 and 5.  If any of those products are saved/updated then i want to invalidate a specific cache tag

Comment: I think you mean cache key, not tag.

Comment: That's probably correct.  Thanks for pointing that out

Answer (score 1):

So you've got a custom cache and you are storing data in it based on the products displayed on screen. And you want to invalidate that cache by removing the entries that match a product ID?

You would need a third and fourth level ideally.

- The first to store the key/value pair
- The second to store the cache_tag/key pair
- *The third to store the product ID/key pair*
- *The fourth to store the product ID/related products IDs*

Then using the two last levels, you could identify all products within the cache group to be purged, and remove the cache entries for each.

Depending on how products are related within the group - you might be able to just just a product method without needing another level of caching, but you haven't made that clear.